Unexpected output in OpenMP parallel Block
The following program, if my understanding is correct, should create at most 10 threads and run the omp parallel block :
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    omp_set_num_threads(10);
#pragma omp parallel
    {
        int id = omp_get_thread_num();

        printf("%d %d %d\n", id, omp_get_num_threads(), omp_get_max_threads());
    }
    return 0;
}

The output shows that it was run 12 times. But omp_get_num_threads() = 1 in all of the threads, and somehow omp_get_max_threads = 12 except for the first thread.
output :
0 1 10
0 1 12
0 1 12
0 1 12
0 1 12
0 1 12
0 1 12
0 1 12
0 1 12
0 1 12
0 1 12
0 1 12

I have compiled the exact same code with cmd line : g++ -fopenmp .\openMp.c -o prog in VS code terminal, the output was expected and is correct :
1 10 10
2 10 10
3 10 10
4 10 10
0 10 10
5 10 10
6 10 10
7 10 10
8 10 10
9 10 10


I have added libomp.lib to : Configuration Properties > Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies
-fopenmp -Xclang flags added to C/C++ > Additional Options
C/C++ > All Options > Open MP Support > Yes
Not sure if there is any libomp.dll, can't find it in MSVC intallation directory.

Note : I am using a 6 cores CPU with 12 logical processors.

Cannot reproduce on VS2022 (17.2.5), on a 10 cores CPU: each line has a different thread id, and all lines have the same num threads (10) / max threads (10). BTW - what is the -Xclang flag supposed to be ? I get ignoring unknown option '-Xclang' when I add it. Same goes to -fopenmp.

I think -Xclang and -fopenmp are not for MSVC. Setting "Open MP Support > Yes" should be what you need (which sets /openmp).

It is not clear what your compiler and environment is : You talk about "VS code" and then "MSVC". The two are pretty different. AFAIK, the former may not use the MSVC compiler. In fact, you say you use GCC. However, you also use -Xclang. Each compiler use its own implementation of OpenMP. Pick 1 specific compiler and do not change or mix parameters related to other compilers. Mixing OpenMP runtimes lead to problems typically like the one you have (or very bad performance issues as well as crashes).

By the way, using omp_set_num_threads manually like that is generally a bad idea, even for testing purposes. Please use OMP_NUM_THREADS instead which is more flexible. In some rare cases, providing the clause num_threads to the parallel section might be suited if a fixed number of thread is required by the application and should never be set by the user (rare).

@JérômeRichard the OP added a Visual Studio tag (not VS code), and also the description of the project settings seems to match Visual Studio. However I agree the OP should clarify to make sure.

I got misled by this answer, I should'nt have added the .lib and the flags too. Thanks to all.

the only thing you need to do in MSVC to enable openmp is to enable it with

C/C++ > Language > Open MP Support > Yes

this step is equivalent to adding a command line argument /openmp
the issue you see is caused by manually linking libomp.lib, you should remove that.
you also shouln't pass -fopenmp -Xclang, as those are clang arguments, not MSVC arguments.
If you are working with multiple compilers and platforms, I recommend you use a build system to automatically set-up your toolchain, CMake has those flags built-in How to set linker flags for OpenMP in CMake's try_compile function, and most IDEs including VSCode and Visual Studio have good support for CMake, and you don't need to learn the quirks of each compiler.

The OP states It uses "VS code" and the command line g++ -fopenmp .\openMp.c -o prog. Since AFAIK MSVC does not support GCC and VS code is a completely different software than MSVC, I do not think an MSVC answer fits to the OP. I think a clarification of the OP is needed though.

@JérômeRichard his question is split into two parts, one in MSVC that is not working, the other is in gcc which is working, he is just wondering why the MSVC behavior is different than the gcc behavior, the question syntax is indeed confusing, but this answer will help him.

It would make sense indeed (let see if this is the case). Note that the OpenMP runtime of MSVC is obsolete and I would personally not recommand using it except for testing purpose (especially on big-little CPUs like most recent Intel ones). Since the experimental version use the Clang runtime, it might accidentally fix the OP problem too (though direct OMP lib linking is bad indeed).
